# How to select a different span value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dropdown which is created using div and span tags.
This is how my current dropdown looks like.

```
<div id="userList>
   <div class="selectOption">
         <span class="selectOption Current" value="mike">Mike</span>
         <span class="selectOption" value="andrew">Andrew</span>
         <span class="selectOption" value="emma">Emma</span>
   </div>
<div>
```

Currently if I press "E" when list is expanded, user Emma is not selected automatically.

I want to select the users by pressing keys on their first letter when this dropdown is opened.

I have researched alot but couldn't find a solution for this.

Can anyone provide me a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried working with keycodes in key event handlers? That's what you would need to use then filter results based on key code.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comment. I'm a new bie to the development. Can you provide me any reference links regarding this? So I can refer that

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Your question does not make clear, what you are going to achieve... Actually, you don't even have a *list*, you have two containers with some `span` elements... You should provide more details, like your CSS or JS files or read some more about HTML, like using list-elements like `ul` and `ol`...

Comment: @Mischback why do you need css for dom filtering question? Why can't span's be used ...they are all siblings of one container?

Comment: @charlietfl Many thanks for your link. However it's bit difficult to me to digest the theory. Can you show me a demo implementation on how to do this?

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, CSS is not relevant, but why is the question tagged with this? Also, I'm a huge fan of semantic markup, so using `div` and `span` for an actual listing seems wrong (while being correct markup). I just tried to point the author into some useful direction. I think this question does not yet meet the requirements of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more than you're looking for, but here is an example that creates a dropdown similar to what you describe. Hopefully you can get some ideas from the example for your project.

The key idea is to use `keyup()` to trap the keypress. However, to prevent errors, we first test to ensure the last element clicked is the dropdown (title div, or one of the spans).

Also, IDs were added to each span to make it simpler to style the clicked span.

<kbd>[**Full jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcp47evg/)</kbd>

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if ( activeEl=='ulTitle' || activeEl=='selectOption' ){
        $('.selectOption').removeClass('Current');

        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code==77 || code==109) { //m or M
            key='m';
            nam='Mike';
        }else if(code==65 || code==97) { //m or M
            key='a';
            nam='Andrew';
        }else if(code==69 || code==101) { //m or M
            key='e';
            nam='Emma';
        }else if(code==13) { //Enter key
            $('#mybutt').click();
        }
        $('.selectOption#'+key).addClass('Current');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What happen if there is two user names starts from same letter?

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked. I suggest that you select a correct answer for this question, and then use this example to ask another question. When you ask a new question, dozens of eyes see the question and try to help, but when you revise an existing question only the one or two (who are following the question) even know about the new question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sure.